# Show that a vector family is an orthonormal basis

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional Euclidean vector space, its scalar product is denoted $<.>$ let $(e_1,..,e_n)$ all of norm 1 be a family of vectors of $V$, we assume that for all $x$ in $V$ :

$\sum(<e_i,x>^2)=||x||^2$

Show that $(e_1,...e_n)$ is an othonormal basis of $V$

I don't know how i am suppose to show that.
As we have that $<e_i,e_j> = 0$ and $||e_i||= 1$, what i am suppose to do ?

Comment: I am reading this as you have already shown that $<e_i,e_j>=0$ for $i\neq j$. Is that right? If so, you need to show that the set of $e_i$ form a basis for $V$.

Comment: @Bawnjourno 1- no i didn't show that, 2- i didn't understand your recommandation, how i am suppose to do it ?

Comment: You have to show that no nonzero  vector can be orthogonal to all  $e_k$ $k=1,2,\ldots, n.$ Another option is to show that $x=\sum \langle x,e_k\rangle e_k$

Comment: @xplayeroni I see. To show $(e_1,\dots, e_n)$ is orthonormal, you need to show the relations you stated: $<e_i,e_j>=0$ for all $i\neq j$ and $||e_i||=1$ for all $i$ (but this norm condition is given). Next, you need to show $e_1,\dots,e_n$ forms a basis for $V$, which means it is a linearly independent spanning set. Does this help?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one possible approach. Consider the linear map $f:V \to \Bbb R^n$ given by
$$
f(x) = (\langle e_1,x\rangle,\dots ,\langle e_n,x\rangle).
$$
From the fact that $\|f(x)\| = \|x\|$ for all $x \in V$, deduce that $f^*f = I$, where $I$ denotes the identity matrix and $f^*$ denotes the adjoint of $f$. From there, verify that for $y = y_1,\dots,y_n \in \Bbb R^n$, we have
$$
f^*(y) = y_1 e_1 + \cdots + y_n e_n.
$$
It follows that the map $f^*f$ is the linear map associated with the matrix whose entries are $\langle e_i,e_j \rangle$ for $1 \leq i,j \leq n$. Conclude that the set $\{e_1,\dots,e_n\}$ is orthonormal.

From there, prove by contradiction that $\operatorname{span}(e_1,\dots,e_n) = V$. Otherwise, there would exist a non-zero vector $x \in \operatorname{span}(e_1,\dots,e_n)^\perp$, which means that $f(x) = 0$, which means that $\|f(x)\| \neq \|x\|$, contradicting our premise.

Thus, $(e_1,\dots,e_n)$ is indeed an orthonormal basis.

Comment: What is wrong with the following argument: Supposing the $e_i$ are orthonormal, let $E=\mathrm{span}\{e_1,\dots ,e_n\}$. Consider $x\in E^\perp$. Then $<e_i,x>=0$ for all $i$. Moreover $0=\sum_i <e_i,x>^2=||x||^2$ so that $x=0$. Thus $E^\perp=\{0\}$ and we have $E=V$.

Comment: @Bawn You're right...

Answer (score 1):

Here's a direct approach. We're going to show (1) that the $e_j$ are all mutually orthogonal, and (2) that they span the space.

1. Let $x=e_j$.  Use the condition
   \begin{align}
   \lVert e_j\lVert^2=\sum_i\lvert\langle e_i, e_j\rangle\rvert^2
   \end{align}
   to show that $\langle e_i, e_j\rangle=0$.

> To do this: \begin{align}1 =\lVert e_j\lVert^2=\sum_i\lvert\langle e_i, e_j\rangle\rvert^2=\lvert\langle e_j , e_j \rangle \rvert^2+\sum_{i\neq j}\lvert\langle e_i,e_j\rangle\rvert^2=\lVert e_j\lVert^4+\sum_{i\neq j}\lvert\langle e_i, e_j\rangle\rvert^2\,.\end{align}Since $\lVert e_j\lVert^4=1$, this implies that sum on the right-hand side must be zero, and since every term in that sum is positive, each term must be zero.  Hence $\langle e_i, e_j\rangle=0$ for $i\neq j$. We can do this for every $j$. Therefore, these vectors are all mutually orthogonal.

2. Suppose by way of contradiction that the vectors $e_j$ do *not* span the space. Then there exists a vector $x\neq 0$ in the orthogonal complement $\operatorname{span}(e_1,\dots,e_n)^{\perp}$ of the span of the $e_i$'s.

> Since $x$ is in the orthogonal complement, then $\langle x,e_i\rangle=0$ for all $i$. But then, \begin{align}\lVert x \rVert^2 = \sum_i\lvert\langle e_i, x\rangle\rvert^2 = 0\,, \end{align}which contradicts the fact that $x\neq0$.